# AWS Cloud front redirecting to custom-origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a distribution in AWS cloud front with custom origin not s3 bucket
origin name: www.example.com
after filling the required details. 
AWS provided a Cloud Front url like: xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
i created CNAME to the CF url to example.com like:

```
xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net example.com
```

Now when i hit the example.com request is redirecting(302) to www.example.com
i wanted to know is this the correct setup then how does caching work here.
if the setup is incorrect how can i hide the custom-origin to the user instead show only example.com or how can i fix the redirection issue.

Note i dont have any redirection setup on server.

your advice is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any other setting like redirect example.com to www.example.com in your DNS settings ?

Comment: i could not guess any relation between coldforont redirection and your example.com to www.example.com redirection.

Comment: *"Note i dont have any redirection setup on server."*  Perhaps not intentionally, but this is your server returning the redirects, which you should be able to confirm by reviewing the server logs.  CloudFront does not autonomously generate redirects.